# Getting error: Could not find generator uploader. (Rails 3 project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a simple project in ruby on rails 3 to do simple file upload. I thought of using Carrierwave.

I created a new rails project:

```
C:\Sites>rails new fileupload

  create
  create  README
  :
  :
  Using sqlite3 (1.3.4)
  Using turn (0.8.2)
  Using uglifier (1.0.3)
  Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

C:\Sites>cd fileupload

C:\Sites\fileupload>rails g uploader file
  Could not find generator uploader.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use carrierwave and use `rails generate uploader File` then you have to be sure that this gem is installed properly. You can check it by command `gem list carrierwave`. If you didn't install it properly then go to https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave and fallow the installation instruction.

As a bonus - there is a complete guide to create file uploader using a good alternative to carrierwave - paperclip: http://www.iamseree.com/application-development/file-upload-handling-with-ruby-on-rails-3-using-paperclip

Comment: thanks Mr.Ireneusz for the response, i checked gem list carrierwave. i got following response, 
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

carrierwave (0.5.7)                                               but  still same error so is there anything i can do

Comment: so it seems that you have installed gem correctly... are you sure that you have this line in gemfile "gem 'carrierwave'". And can you check if this is possible for you to start server?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. Try this:

1. gem uninstall carrierwave
2. add  this line to your gem file: gem 'carrierwave'
3. bundle install
4. rails g uploader file

I'm sure that what has happen is that the carrierwave gem was installed improper, not installing the uploader file into your project.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you get the error

> could not find generator uploader

is when there is improper installation of CarrierWave. CarrierWave provides a generator called uploader to generate an uploader class to which we can pass the name we want to give our uploader. Check that you added in your project-directory Gemfile the code:

```
gem 'carrierwave'
```

and then:

```
bundle install
```

before you run:

```
rails generate uploader uploader-name
```